# sweetalert2 handle json answer

Tags: php, ajax, sweetalert2

I'm making a sweetalert2 with ajax call. I'm with trouble with getting the answer from ajax call working with my call.

My PHP code creates the following output to send to ajax call:

```
    if(crud_delete($mysqli, 'roles', $args) == true){
        $response["status"] = "success";
        $response["message"] = "Role ".$role_name." deleted with success";
        echo json_encode($response);  
    }else{
        $response["status"] = "error";
        $response["message"] = "There was a problem deleting role ".$role_name;
        echo json_encode($response);                               
    }
```

My JS:

```
function DeleteRole(e, id, role){
    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        onOpen: (toast) => {
          toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
          toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
        }
      })

        swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "Do you want to delete Role " + role,
            icon: 'question',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            preConfirm: () => {
                $.ajax({ url: '../../../controllers/call.php',
                data: {
                    dados: JSON.stringify(id),
                    caller: 'DeleteRole',
                    dataType: 'json'
                },
                type: 'POST'})
                .then(response => {
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: response.status,
                        title: response.message
                      })
                })
                .catch(response => {
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: response.status,
                        title: response.message
                      })
                })
              },
              allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
            })

};
```

If anything wrong happens, the **response.status** and **response.message** works just fine since output is raw json outputing the following:

```
{status: "error", message: "ID does not exists."}
```

But if it's a success, the output comes in responseText lower level:

```
abort: function abort(e)​
always: function always()​
catch: function catch(e)​
done: function add()​
fail: function add()​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader(e)​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType(e)​
pipe: function pipe()​
progress: function add()​
promise: function promise(e)
​readyState: 4
​responseText: "Array\n(\n    [0] => id\n)\n{\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Role Administrator deleted with success\"}"
​setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader(e, t)​
state: function state()
​status: 200
​statusCode: function statusCode(e)
​statusText: "OK"
​then: function then(t, n, r)​
<prototype>: {…
```

The responseText output:

```
"Array
(
    [0] => id
)
{"status":"success","message":"Role Administrator deleted with success"}"
```

Already tried access with **output.responseText.status** without success.
How can I access that information? And why when it's a success, it outputs more information than I send in my PHP? Thanks